# is there a continuous and open map on topological vector space X into X such that is not onto and is not constant map?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Could anyone give an example for a non constant  continuous and open map ‎$f‎ : X\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=0$ and that  is not onto (X is topological vector space) and $‎\frac{(f(X)+f(X))}{2}‎\nsubseteq‎ ‎f(X)‎$? 
I suppose there must be some  examples, but I wasn't able to find one yet. 
Thank you for answers.

Comment: what does it mean for a map to be onto?

Comment: onto means surjective

Answer (score 2):

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\arctan(x)$, this is a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Well, the codomain should still be $\mathbb{R}$ to keep everything a tvs.  Then it's no longer onto, but that's okay by OP's question.

Comment: @Randall I guess I could have worded it better but I meant it is a bijection onto $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and therefore not onto when considered as a map to $\mathbb{R}$.